Stokes–Einstein–Sutherland equation
I've been trying to understand how the diffusion coefficient of droplets, $D$, in a gas medium depends on its self-diffusion coefficient, $D_0$, assuming that the particle's friction against the medium is given by the Stokes equation:
$$F = −6\pi \eta Rv.$$
For this, let's take a cylinder of a small area $\mathrm dA$, length $\mathrm dl$, with concentrations of the medium's gas at the ends $C_1$ and $C_2$, and observe the molecules and then the droplets pass through it. $\mathrm{dS}$ and $\mathrm{dl}$ can be chosen so that only $1$ molecule passes at a time. The work $W$ done on it is equal to:
$$W = −6 \pi  \eta Rv \, \mathrm dL.$$
Now, the work done on the droplet is related to the work done on the air molecules by the following ratio:
$$W_{\text{droplet}} = W_{\text{air}} \cdot \frac{(R_{\text{air}}V_{\text{air}})}{(R_{\text{droplet}}V_{\text{droplet}})}.$$
The work done is the amount of energy a particle loses, which corresponds to the change in the particle's energy and thus the system’s energy (the system being the environment from which the particle has exited). Therefore, the gradient $(\mathrm dM/\mathrm dx)$ is proportional to the work $W$ and also proportional to the flux $J$ and the diffusion coefficient $D$ (as derivatives of $C$ and $C$ are constants and are respectively equal).
From this, I initially derived that $D$ is proportional to the radius, but according to the Stokes–Einstein–Sutherland equation, it should actually be inversely proportional to the radius. Here i have to say that the ratios of velocities are leading to the ratios of masses and temperatures, that also don't give the same result as the Stokes-Einstein equation. Additionally, I'm unsure how this equation can be applied, as temperature should drop during diffusion due to each particle losing kinetic energy.
Where have I made a mistake?
